# polychoric matrix created, but "argument is of length zero" come when doing factor analysis

Tags: psych

I am running a factor analysis via psych package.

```
cormat <- polychoric(na.omit(mself1))
##Warning message:
In cor.smooth(mat) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
fa(cormat,nfactors=3,n.obs = 183 ,n.iter=1, rotate="oblimin",fm="ml")
## Error in if (dim(r)[1] == dim(r)[2]) { : argument is of length zero
```

I just wondered why the argument is of length zero which means the file is empty, when I type cormat the Polychoric matrix came out.

How could I fix this problem, or it has anything with the "not positive definite"?

Thanks!

Comment: Already fixed via cormat <- polychoric(na.omit(mself1))[[1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/) package stores the actual matrix in $rho in your cormat object.  In your case, `fa(cormat$rho)` will fix that problem.  Bill also includes the `fa.poly()` function, which will compute the polychoric correlations from a raw data matrix before running a factor analysis on that.

Be a bit cautious with your results though.  Your resulting matrix was non-Gamian (i.e., had a negative eigenvalue), which can happen when they're estimated pairwise or you have large sampling errors (see Garrido, Abad, & Ponsosa, 2013).